# vagrant backtrack 5 release 3 box

Tags: vagrant, backtrack-linux

is there a working box for backtrack 5 release 3 ( bt5r3 ) that is working with vagrant ?

or a tutorial on how to make the box to work with vagrant ?

i've tried to make the box myself but i had no luck, because the vagrant docs about making the boxes is not informative...

also this [repo](https://github.com/hornos/vagrant-backtrack-r3) doesn't describe how to get it running ? or if that it's working or not ?

if anybody had luck installing a working bt5r3 version on vagrant, please share with us.

if anybody has a working script to install bt5r3 tools on vagrant precise64 box, please share with us.

Comment: Were you ever able to make a Backtrack 5 box?

Comment: No... Tedious work and in the end it didn't work properly , so i'm trying kali linux but the vagrant image is not downloading properly

Comment: I also encountered similar problems. I had the `.vmwarevm` file, but vagrant would not allow me to convert it to a `.box`.

Comment: If you managed to make it please add the steps or upload it somewhere

Answer (score 2):

BackTrack 5R3 has a 32-bit GNOME VMware image for download, grab that.

Convert it using free VMware OVF Tool (latest is v3.5.0 I think) to OVF/OVA and then import it into VirtualBox. You can even directly attach the vmdk images to a newly created vbox VM and see if it boots up, if so, configure the as per the Vagrant [base box package guide](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/base_boxes.html)

Once done, use vagrant package to export the BT 5R3 VM to a vagrant .box file.

For example: `vagrant package --base vbox_vm_name_or_uuid --output /path/to/bt5r3.box`

Comment: that is not an easy way... specially the base box package guide... will try it and see what i'll get